# Running opencv in a thread, unable to start a second time

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-multithreading

When I try to start openvc in a thread, its working once, but after I call it a second time, it won’t start again. The code stuck’s when it reaches a cv2 function in this casecv2.imshow()  (but after cv2.VideoCapture()). 
If I call the start_videofeed() function right after it receives the signal of the socket, its working properly, but I would like to have the sock.recvfrom() to continue receiving for other commands.

This code is only a small example of my script, but I tried a lot and also searched on web but I couldn’t find any answer, only others with similar problems.

I’m running the latest opencv-python package, with python3.8 on manjaro.

I hope someone knows an answer how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import cv2


class VideoFeed():
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 0
        self.window_name = "Video"


    def run(self):
        sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
        sock.bind( ('',54666) )

        while True:
            d, addr = sock.recvfrom( 1024 )
            payload = d.decode()
            if payload == "show_video":
                self.start_video()
            if payload == "exit":
                break

    def start_video(self):
        vs = Thread(target=self.start_videofeed)
        vs.start()



    def start_videofeed(self): 
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.url) 
        if (cap.isOpened()== False):  
          print("Error opening video file")
        print("Starting videofeed") 
        while True:
            ret, self.frame = cap.read() 
            cv2.imshow(self.window_name, self.frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(10)

            if key == 27 or key == ord('q'):
                break
            if cv2.getWindowProperty(self.window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) < 1:        
                break


        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cap.release()
        print("Video release and Destroy")
        return



vf = VideoFeed()
vf.run()
```

Edit:

I finally found an answer. It seems it's not possible to start the video from or in a thread a second time, so I set a boolean in the socket thread to start the videofeed from the main program.

```
class VideoFeed():
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "http://192.168.178.103:8081"
        self.window_name = "Video"
        self.start_video = False

    def run(self):
        Thread(target=self.start_socket).start()

        while True:
            if self.start_video:
                self.start_videofeed()
                self.start_video = False



    def start_socket(self):
        sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
        sock.bind( ('',54666) )

        while True:
            d, addr = sock.recvfrom( 1024 )
            payload = d.decode()
            if payload == "show_video":
                self.start_video = True
            if payload == "exit":
                break


    def start_videofeed(self): 
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.url) 
        if (cap.isOpened()== False):  
          print("Error opening video file")
        print("Starting videofeed") 
        while True:
            ret, self.frame = cap.read() 
            cv2.imshow(self.window_name, self.frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(10)

            if key == 27 or key == ord('q'):
                break
            if cv2.getWindowProperty(self.window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) < 1:        
                break


        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cap.release()
        print("Video release and Destroy")
        return
```